# Create an overlay after clicking on DIV1 with DIV1 content in it

Tags: jquery

Basically, I have a page of contents all placed in .box.

What I need is to get create an overlay when I click on .box and have .box contents in the overlay.

I am not exactly sure if I am doing it right since I am very new at jQuery.  I created a class .overlay and add the class to .box on click but it's not working at all.  This is my code so I hope someone can guide me to the right direction.

```
.overlay {
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 10000;
}

(function () {

$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".box").click(function(){
           $(".overlay").removeClass("overlay");
           $(this).addClass("overlay");
   });   

       $(document).click(function(){
           $(".overlay").removeClass("overlay");
       });
   });
}(jQuery));
```

html

```
<div class="box overlay">
<p>content></p>
</div>
```

Comment: what does this mean? "create an overlay when I click on .box and have .box contents in the overlay."  Are you trying to do something like a modal overlay?

Comment: Something like lightbox2 .. but I only need a simple overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have this code

```
$(document).click(function(){
           $(".overlay").removeClass("overlay");
       });
```

it will remove `overlay` class whenever there is an click event, since as per your question you just need it to be removed on click of `.box`, you dont need this code or in case you are removing it on click of any specific element then please provide appropriate selector for that element like id, class e.t.c.

Edit As per comment:

Currenly you are adding overlay class when element is loaded, which is causing the issue.

Change your html to

```
<div class="box">
   <p>content></p>
</div>
```

Your javascript

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").removeClass("overlay");
    $(this).addClass("overlay");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/CsztD/4/)

Comment: I have removed those lines and tried if the class .overlay will be added to .box on click but it still didn't work.  Is there any syntax error or maybe I am doing it all wrong?

Comment: well no syntax error, can you show some html of yours, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/CsztD/1/) on click it does remove and add class

Comment: Added html, what I get now is the overlay once the page is loaded.  I want the overlay to be hidden and only appear when I click on .box .. I think I am at the wrong direction

Comment: Trying it out and it still doesn't add overlay to my .box class.  I forgot to mention one thing. My .box class has .w and .h added to it.  I defined different preset width and height value, does that affect the jQuery execution?

Comment: I added the width and height CSS on fiddle and it worked so I am not sure what is wrong.  Is there any another approach to create an overlay like this?